# Msg * in batch needs new line how?

Tags: batch-file, msg

Im running the following code snipet

```
Msg * "Hoi %username%, je kunt nu alle vensters sluiten en AutoCAD opniew opstarten"
```

but i want a new line after %username% how can i achieve this?

EDDIT:

```
    ECHO PROOF OF FILE EXECUTION: > "%username%'s proof of file execution.txt"
ECHO.

ECHO EXECUTED BY:   %username%      >> "%username%'s proof of file execution.txt"
ECHO ON:        %date%          >> "%username%'s proof of file execution.txt"
ECHO AT:        %time%          >> "%username%'s proof of file execution.txt"
ECHO .

ECHO PC DETAILS:
ECHO .
ECHO COMPUTER:      %COMPUTERNAME%      >> "%username%'s proof of file execution.txt"

Msg * "Hoi %username% je kunt nu alle vensters sluiten en AutoCAD opniew opstarten"
```

Comment: Is there diffrent types then? I used notepad to create this and it works thats all i know (see edit will have whole code)

Comment: I have one more relating question more of an irritation is i was taught that ECHO. would produce a blank line thsi is not working can anybody ellaberate on that also?

Comment: It should be `ECHO.`, there is no space between them.

Answer (score 3):

The question is, what is "Msg", is it a batch is it an exe file?
Does it support a < Linefeed >?

You can try this, perhaps it works.

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set lf=^


rem Two blank lines (without spaces are neccessary)
Msg * "Hoi %username%!lf! je kunt nu alle vensters sluiten en AutoCAD opniew opstarten"
```

But if it works, depends of the Msg-Command

Comment: i tried this command and the result of me using "set lf=^" is "more?" what do i type when it says, "more?"

Comment: Which part of the expample is unclear? "Two blank lines, without spaces are neccessary" ;-)

Answer (score 3):

```
@echo off
msg * Hello^

World!^

Bye^

at^

all!
```

Output:

```
Hello
World!
Bye
at
all!
```

With variable:

```
@echo off
(set msg1=Hello^^^

^

)
msg * %msg1%World!
```

Output

```
Hello
World!
```

Answer (score 2):

Jeb's answer didn't work for me. The linefeed made msg skip all text following it

The solution is to create a template msg.txt file containing the newlines and piping that into msg:

```
echo Hoi %username% >msg.txt
echo. >>msg.txt
echo je kunt nu alle vensters sluiten en AutoCAD opniew opstarten >>msg.txt

type msg.txt |msg *
```

Answer (score 2):

All examples presented here are either complex and contain unnecessary code, or they will work with errors. Especially when you want to print many other "ANSI" characters through "Msg".

*The code has been tested in many variations. It is simple and works stably:*

**`(echo %str1%&echo %str2%)|msg "%username%"`** *or* **`*`**

*Example:*
*Win+R >* **cmd /c "`@(echo More Strings&echo.&echo   For You !)|@msg *`"**

*Result:*
[MsgBox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MgJ2h.png)